# jw player won't play VAST video tag

Tags: jwplayer, google-dfp, vast

jw player won't play video served with DFP out-of-page.

```
<script src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>

<div id='div-gpt-ad-x-0'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/xx/oustream_Video', 'div-gpt-ad-x-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-x-0');});                        
  </script>
</div>
```

With the above code called with test video `localhost/my-page?apextest=1`, i can see the jw initiating network ad getting ad respond with VAST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VAST version="2.0">
  <Ad id="TestAd">
    <InLine>
     <AdSystem>...</AdSystem>
     <AdTitle>VAST 2.0 Linear Ad</AdTitle>
     <Impression></Impression>
     <Creatives>
        <MediaFile ...
     </Creatives>
   </InLine>
 </Ad>
</VAST>
```

but nothing get played. no popup or any error message in my console. and copying one of the link in the media file into browser address bar I can play the video file. what might the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

What is the media file in the VAST response?
Which ad client are you using, VAST or Googima?

Is the player reporting any ad errors? Here is the code I use to debug ad events:

```
jwplayer().on('adError',function(e){console.log(e.message+' -- '+e.tag);});
jwplayer().on('adRequest',function(e){console.log('Just requested an ad: '+e.tag);});
jwplayer().on('adImpression',function(e){console.log('Ad impression! '+e.tag);});
jwplayer().on('adStarted',function(e){console.log('Ad started! '+e.tag);});
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to point to an actual XML file located on your file system, it will not load sending XML as a string.